# Having overload methods from one abstract method in JAVA

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract

Given an abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractStomach {
    public abstract void consume(Food food);
}
```

I want to have some concrete classes with different overloading methods:

```
public class FruitStomach extends AbstractStomach {
    public static class Apple extends Food {}
    public static class Orange extends Food {}
    @Override
    public void consume(Apple food) {...}
    @Override
    public void consume(Orange food) {...}
}

public class MeatStomach extends AbstractStomach {
    public static class Beef extends Food {}
    @Override
    public void consume(Beef food) {...}
}
```

The above doesn't work as it is forcing me to implement also the generic `consume(Food)` abstract method in each concrete class.

But I dont want the concrete classes to implement `consume(Food)` as that has been taken care of by their overloading variants and really, each concrete class should consume different and specific food only, not ANY food, so that

```
AbstractStomach stomach = new FruitStomach();
stomach.consume(new Beef());
```

should give an error.

If I remove the abstract method in the abstract class then there is no point to have them extending the abstract class as it provides no guidance to them what to implement.

How do you fix the above design so that each concrete classes can have their overloading methods yet they know there is an abstract method `consume()` to implement but do not need to implement `consume(Food)`.

Edit

---

I can resolve the above without using overloading, e.g.

```
public class FruitStomach extends AbstractStomach {
    public static class Apple extends Food {}
    public static class Orange extends Food {}
    @Override
    public void consume(Food food) {
        if (food instanceof Apple) {
           ...
        } else if (food instanceof Orange) {
           ...
        } else {
           // throws an error
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not what I want. I would like to see a solution that uses method overloading.

Comment: you're forgetting the word `class` while declaring them.

Comment: In Java, an overloaded method is selected at compile time, not run time, so a caller who had some `Food` but didn't know what type it was (say, it had been passed into it) would never be able to call the correct overload of `consume`. The Java type system is not suited to what you are trying to do.

Comment: wow 5 answers in about about a 2 minute span.

Comment: "I would like to see a solution that uses method overloading"... sorry, you're not going to see that, not in Java.  Deciding at run time which method to execute is called _polymorphism_, and as [this site](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/overriding-and-overloading-in-java-with-examples/) makes clear, "Polymorphism applies to overriding, not to overloading"--which is the same as what David said that overloaded methods are selected at compile time, not run time.

Comment: Why do you need to implement different type of stomach by inheritance? Aren't generics enough to support this situation?

Comment: @STaefi Generics don't give you polymorphism.  It may be that generics are good enough for this OP's case, but we don't have enough code to know.

Comment: That's right @ajb. But the point I'm trying to say is in many cases like this we don't actually need polymorphism for the type checking purpose of this question. You are more exprienced so let me know if I'm getting something wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @STaefi You're not wrong, except that I just don't think you can talk about "cases like this" when there's a lack of info.  We don't know how he intends to use these classes.  So we don't really know what kind of cases are like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abstract methods in abstract classes are more than about "providing guidance what to implement".  Abstract classes allow you to have objects that can be of *any* subclass of the abstract class.  That is, you can have a method like

```
public void evaluateDigestion(AbstractStomach stomach) {
}
```

and you can call it with any kind of `Stomach` object, a `FruitStomach` or a `MeatStomach` or a `DessertStomach` or whatever.  Inside `evaluateDigestion`, the method can call `stomach.consume(someKindOfFood)`.  Since this is the `consume` defined for the abstract class (at compile time, `evaluateDigestion` doesn't know what the class is), it is the `consume` that uses a `Food` parameter.  Then, at run time, the call to `consume` will "dispatch" to the `consume(Food food)` method defined for the concrete class.  That's why a `consume` with a `Food` parameter has to be defined for each concrete class.  The dispatching call doesn't search through overloading methods with `Apple`, `Orange`, etc., parameters; Java doesn't do that.  (So your statement that it "has been taken care of by the overloading variants" is incorrect; there is a big difference between overloading and overriding, which can be confusing to newcomers.)

So you do have to write

```
public void consume(Food food)
```

in each concrete class.  A *very clunky* way to implement this would be

```
public void consume(Food food) {
    if (food instanceof Apple) {
        consume((Apple)food);  // calls the overloaded version because you've use a cast to tell Java how to view the object
    } else if (food instanceof Orange) {
        consume((Orange)food);
    } else {
        throw ... // some exception that occurs when you try to eat the wrong kind of food
    }
}
```

Better would be to define an abstract method in `Food`, assuming `Food` is abstract:

```
public abstract class Food {
    public void abstract consumedBy(AbstractStomach stomach);
}
```

Define concrete versions in the `Apple` and `Orange`, etc, classes, and then write `consume` like

```
public static void consume(Food food) {
    food.consumedBy(this);
}
```

However, this wouldn't prevent an attempt to get a `FruitStomach` to consume beef.  You may have to use `instanceof` to make sure the food is compatible.  (One possibility: define a class `Fruit` that extends `Food`, and make `Apple` and `Orange` subclasses of `Fruit`; then you can say `food instanceof Fruit` to verify that it's the right kind of food.  There may be a better design pattern than this, though.  I can't think of one offhand.)

Comment: Love the knowledge you have on this topic. Picking yours as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could use generics to (partially) solve your problem:

AbstractStomach defines a type parameter `T` which declares what type of `Food` it consumes:

```
public abstract class AbstractStomach<T extends Food> {
    public abstract void consume(T food);
}
```

Then you can declare a food type `Fruit` and the corresponding `FruitStomach`:

```
public class Fruit extends Food {}
public class FruitStomach extends AbstractStomach<Fruit> {
    public static class Apple extends Fruit {}
    public static class Orange extends Fruit {}
    @Override
    public void consume(Fruit food) {}
}
```

and the similar classes `Meat` and `MeatStomach`:

```
public class Meat extends Food {}
public class MeatStomach extends AbstractStomach<Meat> {
    public static class Beef extends Meat {}
    @Override
    public void consume(Meat food) {}
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks, but this just pushes the issue from `consume(Food)` to `consume(Fruit)`. Within that, you still need to check the instance of Fruit whether its an apple or an orange.

Comment: @user1589188 The check whether the instance of Fruit is an apple or an orange is still needed, but within `consume(Fruit)` it is always a `Fruit` and never some kind of `Meat`. As I've written: it partially solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To @Override a method you need to have the same exact tipe of return or a subtype, name and parameters so you can't change "Food food" in "Orange orange".

What i think you can do is a cast at the object you need to work on inside your method in concrete classes (or as you do using instanceof). Or maybe better you can create an object:

```
Food orange = new Orange();
Food apple = new Apple();
```

And so use the first time method override in Orange class and second time the one method in Apple class.

If it's not solution you want please comment so i can try something else.

Comment: Your first sentence is not correct. Since Java 5 covariant returns have been permitted. An overloading method can return a subtype of the return type of the method it overloads.

Comment: But i thought using @Override annotation you need to use the same exact method of implemented interfaces or extended class. I'll find some documentation about to argument it, thanks for the advice.

Comment: If you have a method that returns `T`, you can override it with a method that returns `T2` if `T2` is a subclass of `T` (since Java 5).  That's the only exception to the rule about using the same exact method.  The parameter types still have to be the same (no subclasses allowed).

Comment: Thanks ajb i've seen documentation some minutes ago and edited post.

Answer (score 1):

```
The above doesn't work as it is forcing me to implement also the generic consume(Food)
```

That's the **right** behavior. By contract in abstract class `AbstractStomach`, you agree that,

> Anything which extends `AbstractStomach` will have a method
>   `consume(Food)` (**any food**) and then in subclass you are
>   forcing it to have only **two** types of food, thus bypassing the contract.

Comment: I would rather like to see a contract that says "at least one food" not "any food" :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing is that your abstract method signature expects a super class called **Food** to be passed into the consume-method. Every implementation of this abstract class (and therefore its abstract method) must override the same signature.

e.g.

```
   public FruitStomach extends AbstractStomach {
    public static class Apple extends Food {}
    public static class Orange extends Food {}
    @Override
    public void consume(Food food) {
      if (food instanceof Orange) {
        Orange orange = (Orange) food;
        // do smth. with orange     
      } else{
        // so smth with food
      }
    }

   public MeatStomach extends AbstractStomach {
      public static class Beef extends Food {}
      @Override
      public void consume(Food food) {
        Beef beef = (Beef) food;
        // do smth. with beef...
      }
    }
```

could work. Although this is not very clean code and you got no compile-time verification if your code is wired together correctly.
But as you stated, if you call the wrong Stomach.consume()-method on the wrong input food, you might raise a ClassCastException, which you could handle.

Comment: Yea, can't find alternatives other than using `instanceof`. Not really elegant, but thats so much we can do.